# Filestreaming to html5 in PHP without writing a file to the filesystem

Tags: php, video, streaming

I'm fairly new to PHP and definitely new to streaming video.

I have mp4 videos stored in a filestream column of my SQL SERVER, and I'd like to stream them to HTML5 video.

I've managed to use the following stream class ( http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial ) by providing it a temporary file via 'file_put_contents($filePath, $queryresult),' but having to depend on writing and then cleaning up an intermediate file in the filesystem is problematic in the end.

Am I missing a key concept that would allow me to stream a file directly from the DB to the video "src" without having to write to a file in between?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't access: http://codesamplez.com/

Comment: I don't seem to have a problem following the link...

Comment: I would just alter the codesample and remove the read from file part in the stream() function then replace it by read from sql stream...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, here's my final result, which seems to work well without needing temp files.

Not certain if it would make more sense to include the query into the class and just pass the $MediaFileID to the class, but this works as is, so for now I've left it.

The entire modified class is included with its original credit info:

```
function ExecutereadMediaSP($MediaFileID){

    try{

    $connection = ConnectToDB();

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

    // logs basic info about media viewer.  Mainly for a basic hit counter.
    LogMediaRequest($connection, $MediaFileID);

    //Selects binary data from SQL Server based on MediaFileID.  Passes this to Stream Class.  May be able to make further improvements later.
    $sql = "SELECT ... data from FILESTREAM column based on file ID ...";   

    $rst = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $rst->execute();
    $rst->bindColumn(1, $filecontent, PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);

    $row = $rst->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//sql can only return one row due to unique identifier

    //Stream file 
    $stream = new VideoStream($filecontent);
    $stream->start();

    //Clean up.
    $rst->closeCursor();
    unset($rst);
    $connection = null;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log("Error in getting video\n".$e->getMessage(),0);
    }

}


/**
 * VideoStream - PHP class that supports (adaptive) streaming of files
 *
 * @author Rana
 * modified by HazCod to use stream_get_contents and correct session shutoff
 * https://github.com/HazCod
 * @link http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial
 */
class VideoStream
{
    private $path = "";
    private $stream = "";
    private $buffer = 102400;
    private $start  = -1;
    private $end    = -1;
    private $size   = 0;

    function __construct($filecontent) 
    {


        try{

        // Opens file handle resource to replace use of actual file in the file system.
        $file_handle = fopen('php://memory', 'r+', false, stream_context_create()); 

        // Writes data from SQL Query to file wrapper.
        fwrite($file_handle, $filecontent);

        // Moves pointer to beginning of file.
        fseek($file_handle, 0);

        // Gets info on the "file."  Required to get filesize.
        $fstat = array();

        // gather statistics
        $fstat = fstat($file_handle);

        //Set File Size for Stream Class.
        $this->size  = $fstat['size'];

        // Define Stream as "File."
        $this->stream = $file_handle;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log("Error in getting video\n".$e->getMessage(),0);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Set proper header to serve the video content
     */
    private function setHeader()
    {   
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
      //  header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
        $this->start = 0;

        $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
       // header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

            $c_start = $this->start;
            $c_end = $this->end;

            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];

                $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            $this->start = $c_start;
            $this->end = $c_end;
            $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
            fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header("Content-Length: ".$length);
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
        }
        else
        {
            header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
        }  

    }

    /**
     * close curretly opened stream
     */
    private function end()
    {
        fclose($this->stream);
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * perform the streaming of calculated range
     */
    private function stream()
    {
        $i = $this->start;
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end && connection_aborted() == 0) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
            if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
                $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
            }
            $data = stream_get_contents($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
            echo $data;
            flush();
            $i += $bytesToRead;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start streaming video content
     */
    function start()
    {
        session_write_close(); //ensure our session is written away before streaming, else we cannot use it elsewhere
        $this->setHeader();
        $this->stream();
        $this->end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were creating temp files yourself and then deleting it. Then you can improve the process by using PHP's inbuilt 
`tempfile()` which

> Creates a temporary file with a unique name in read-write (w+) mode and returns a file handle .The file is automatically removed when closed (for example, by calling fclose(), or when there are no remaining references to the file handle returned by tmpfile()), or when the script ends.

```
private function open()
{
    if ( !($this->stream = tmpfile()) ) {
        fwrite($this->stream, $videodata);
        rewind($this->stream);
        die('Could not open stream for reading');
    }
    // now your temp file is ready to be read.
}
```

So now you have no responsibility of temp. deletion PHP will handle that for you.If you need to customize the temp. file name or get details you may use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php

If you don't want to use files at all and rather want to use purely in memory solution then you can try using memory streams

```
private function open()
{
    if ( !($this->stream = fopen('php://memory', 'wb+') ) ) {
        fwrite($this->stream, $videodata);
        rewind($this->stream);
        die('Could not open stream for reading');
    }
    // now your in-memory file is ready to be read.
}
```

You can fread, fwrite, file_get_contents on the memory stream or throw it over the network using the tcp streams. But I must say that the second solution is a bit memory intensive so not suitable for streaming huge files.

Comment: OMG sweet!  I'd still like to try for being able to do it without a file, but this may solve my MAJOR problem, which is that unlink doesn't always seem to work, and IE seems to trigger THREE files to be created (GRRR), which could crash my server.  lol!  

As for the streams, I'm going to keep trying and thanks for the hints!

Comment: Yea go for the 1st solution I have used it and it works perfect.The second one is good only if you stream small files like just a few Mbs coz all data gets loaded in RAM and swap ; larger files will coz your swap(assuming you have swap) file to get exhausted very rapidly.If you don't have swap then all stuff grts loaded in RAM alone.... and soon you would see out of memory error and server crash

Comment: Ok, so I've successfully used your temp file process, but it's still giving me a problem, and I can't see examples of this behavior anywhere..

In IE only, just as previously when I would browse to the page and it would create several files of one of the found videos, and would not unlink them all, even now using temp files, when browsing to the page three temp files are created each time, and they are not deleted at the end, so they sit in the temp directory until I manually clear them.  It's like IE is seeing the reference in the video tag, and hitting it several times with no click needed

Comment: Strange... I think this might be due to IE not supporting range requests for each seek operation IE might be spawning new php process instead of using the same.Which version is it btw?

Comment: IE 11.  

And this seems to be at least PART of the issue.  As soon as IE sees the video tag, it hits it, which triggers file creation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639381/preventing-ie-edge-from-preloading-video

But I also suspect that there is some reason that it's making multiple requests to the link in the process, which is causing MULTIPLE file creation, even before a user clicks to watch the video.

Comment: Can you sample IE request and server response headers? I feel it all has to do with `header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);` this part , try commenting and see

Comment: Commented out that line, but no change.

Comment: Ok, I found out that if a Poster is set, then IE doesn't hit the links.  Just now means I'll have to add a step to the upload process to build thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a temporary file seems like a temporary workaround for me. As you are getting a stream from the database and you need to serve a stream to the client, there is no need to store data on the harddisk at all.

All you need to do is to replace the part of your linked example that reads from file (and echo's the binary content to the client) and make it read from sql instead.

In your linked example function stream(), replace this part

```
    while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
        $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
        if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
        }
        $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
        echo $data;
        flush();
        $i += $bytesToRead;
    }
```

Replace by somthing like this:

```
/* Execute the query. */  
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);  
if( $stmt === false )  
{  
     echo "Error in statement execution.</br>";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  

/* Retrieve and display the data.  
The return data is retrieved as a binary stream. */  
if ( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) )  
{  
   $videostream = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0,   
                      SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));  
   //header("Content-Type: image/jpg");  
   fpassthru($videostream );  
}  
else  
{  
     echo "Error in retrieving data.</br>";  
     die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}
```